# difficult to press button in tableviewcell

Tags: ios, uitableview

The tableviewcell have few buttons, but it difficult to press.
for example:
button 1: position(10,10,20,20)
but i have change the button position using code to position(20,20,20,20). 
is it the caused make it difficult to press or have any idea make it easy to press

Comment: have you please check the size of the UITableView Cell Size?

Comment: There are two approaches to solving this: (a) make humans grow smaller fingers, and (b) make buttons bigger. Pick a solution that you think would be easier to implement in your app :-)

Comment: @Nimit Parekh my tableview cell size is depend on the content, so it will be flexible.

Comment: @user4302196 you need to create the button bigger.

Comment: i have tried to create the button more bigger but it still difficult to press

Comment: have any other way beside make the button bigger?

Comment: a button with size of _20 by 20_ it quite small, increase its size up to _35 by 35_ or _44 by 44_ (as the HIG recommends, maybe) and your difficulties stop being.

Comment: @holex is it too big size if it is share button like in facebook?

Comment: you may need to increate the _tappable_ area only for a better UX, the image still can be tiny in the middle of the button.

Comment: @holex is working better now. Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding button in TableViewCell's content view programatically or by the interface builder ?

You should try with programmatically instead of IB.

Comment: i added using interface builder

Comment: You should try programmatically.

Comment: i tried but still the same situation. difficult to press as well